# Show a $C^*$-algebra admits an approximate kind of identity.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I'm reading the book "An invitation to $C^*$-algebra's" by William Arveson and I'm focused on the proof of proposition 1.3.1, which says:

> Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $J$ be a closed two-sided ideal of $A$.
>   Then for every $x \in J$ there is a sequence $(e_n)_n$ of
>   self-adjoint elements of $J$ with
>
> $$Sp_A(e_n) \subseteq [0,1], \quad  \lim_n \Vert xe_n - x \Vert = 0$$

The author provides a proof in the case that $A$ has a unit and concludes by saying that the case where $A$ has no unit follows by adjoining a unit, leaving the details to the reader.

So, suppose $A$ has no unit. Then consider the unitalisation $A_I:=A \oplus \mathbb{C}$.

Maybe I can show that $J$ is a two-sided ideal in $A_I$?

So, let $a + \lambda 1 \in A_I$ and $x \in J$ ( $a \in A, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$). Then

$$(a+\lambda1)x = ax + \lambda x$$

and if I can show that $\lambda x \in J$, I can show that $J$ is also a two-sided ideal in $A_I$.

However, I don't see why this should be true.

Comment: Ideals in algebras are sub-vectorspaces (by definition), so closed under scalar multiplication!

Comment: @s.harp Why is an ideal a sub-vectorspace? I can see this is true if $A$ has a unit, but we don't have that here.

Comment: Check the definition of an ideal in your text. Usually it is defined to be a "subspace" or a "sub-algebra" of the original space.

Comment: Ideal in my text means closed two-sided ideal, in the ring-theoretic sense.

Comment: Ok, then it is possible to prove the statement. Note that $A$ is an ideal in the unitisation $A_I$ so there is an approximate identity $e_n$ of $A$ by what you have already seen. Then $\lambda x =\lim_n  \lambda e_n x$ where $\lambda e_n x\in J$ since $\lambda e_n\in A$ and $J$ is an ideal of $A$. Since you are asking for $J$ to  also be closed you find that the limit $\lambda x\in J$.

Comment: You might want to turn this into an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A$ is a closed two-sided ideal in $A_I$, and that $A_I$ is unital. So there is an approximate $e_n$ unit in $A$ by what you have already seen. Note that $e_n x\to x$ for all $x\in A$, from which follows that $xe_n=(e_n x^* )^* \to (x^*)^*=x$ by continuity of the $*$-operation (ie a left approximate unit is also a right approximate unit).

Now let $J$ be a closed left ideal (in the ring-theoretic sense) of $A$ (or right ideal, or two-sided). It follows that $\lambda e_n x\in J$ (resp. $x (\lambda e_n)\in J$) for all $x\in J$. Since $J$ is also closed you have that $\lambda x= \lim_n \lambda e_n x\in J$ (similarly $\lambda x = \lim_n x(\lambda e_n)\in J$).

Comment: Maybe you are willing to have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620501/let-j-be-a-closed-ideal-in-a-c-algebra-a-prove-that-a-j-is-a-c-al ?