# Let $J$ be a closed ideal in a $C^*$-algebra $A$. Prove that $A/J$ is a $C^*$-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $J$ a closed two-sided ideal of $A$. I want to show that $A/J$ with the quotient norm is a $C^*$-algebra as well, for the $*$-operation $(a+J)^*:= a^*+J$.

In the book I'm reading, the author provides a proof in the case that $A$ has a unit, so I can assume my algebra is non-unital.

Attempt:

Consider the unitalisation $A_I$. We have that $J$ is a norm-closed twosided ideal in $A_I$ and consequently, we see that $A_I/J$ is a $C^*$-algebra. Since $A \subseteq A_I$, we see that

$$A/J \subseteq A_I/J$$

and thus the $C^*$-identity in $A_I/J$ is inherited by $A/J$, which ends the proof.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small detail you may want to mention is that the inclusion $A/J\hookrightarrow A_I/J$ is isometric.  Other than that, everything seems fine.

Comment: Yes, this follows because the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow A_I$ is isometric. Thank you!